# Alternating least squares --- what are the limitations?

Tags: machine-learning, recommender-system, matrix-decomposition

I am taking an introductory course to Machine Learning and we learned alternating least squares for recommender systems. I learned that this method has some advantages --- easy to parallelize, and ideal to predict implicit data. But does this algorithm have any main disadvantages or limitations?